# How can I make Visual Studio window be highlighted when it is active?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have difficulties seeing my Visual Studio 2012 window is active. Is there any way I can make the Visual Studio 2012 window behave like a standard window.

Visual Studio 2012 behavior (I can't tell the difference):

Active:
[image: visual studio 2012 active window]

Inactive:
[image: visual studio 2012 inactive window]

Standard window behavior (much easier to see when active):

Active:
[image: standard window active]

Inactive:

[image: standard window inactive]

I would like to avoid using the operating system high contrast setting if at all possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @mandaleeka suggested I ended up using the Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor extension.

But an even better highlighting option in my case is to change the "Main Window -> Caption" -> "Active" -> "Background" color.

Here is my resulting theme:

[image: window bar clear visible in the top of the VS 2012 window]

Answer (score 3):

One workaround to this is to install the [Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) and modify one of the built in themes to change the inactive window border color.

After installing the extension, go to Tools -> Customize Colors. Select a theme to copy colors from, give it a name, and hit "Create". In the color editor, scroll down to the "Main Window" section and under "Inactive" change Border to something that stands out.

Here is an example:

[image: example]